# Are there other methods to prove this FLittleT variation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $u,v$ two prime numbers such as $u\ne v$. Then $u^{v-1}+v^{u-1}\equiv 1 \ [uv]$.

To prove it :

I introduce the system : $
\begin{cases}
  x\equiv 1\ [u] \\
  x\equiv 1 \ [v]
\end{cases}$

We have the trivial solution $x=1$.

Moreover according to CRT with $\gcd(u,v)=1$, we have $x=1\times \frac{uv}{u}\times y_1+1\times \frac{uv}{v} \times y_2$ which is a solution for the system. We have the conditions that : $vy_1\equiv 1\ [u]$ ans $uy_2\equiv 1 \ [v]$. By applying FLT and CRT, $x=v^{u-1}+u^{v-1}$ is a solution $[uv]$.

Then $u^{v-1}+v^{u-1}\equiv 1 \ [uv]$.

So are there other methods which suggest not to use these famous theorems, and which is more elementary to prove this result ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are p and q?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury ought to be u,v see towards the end.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury indeed just a typing error

Comment: Fermat's little theorem and the Chinese remainder theorem are reasonably elementary. Moreover, the point of knowing theorems is so that we don't have to reinvent the wheel with every new problem. So why would we want a different proof?

Comment: @GregMartin for instance $u,v$ two different prime numbers with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. So by FLT $u$ divides $v^{u-1}-1$ and $v$ divides $u^{v-1}$ and in that case : $uv$ divides $(u^{v-1}-1)(v^{u-1})$. So $uv$ divides $uv^{(u+v-2)}-u^{v-1}-v^{u-1}+1$. So, there exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such as : $kuv=uv^{(u+v-2)}-u^{v-1}-v^{u-1}+1\Leftrightarrow u^{v-1}+v^{u-1}\equiv 1 [uv]$. This method don't use CRT.

Comment: @GregMartin *$v$ divides $u^{v-1}-1$ sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $x=u^{v-1} + v^{u-1}$. As you have proved, from FLT, 
        $$x=u^{v-1} + v^{u-1} \equiv 1 (\mod u)$$
and
                $$x=u^{v-1} + v^{u-1} \equiv 1 (\mod v).$$

In other words, you have proved $ u|y, v|y$, where $y=x-1$. It is a fundamental theorem that 
     $$gcd(u, v) = 1, u|y, v|y  \Rightarrow uv|y$$

To prove the above theorem, you can use Bezout's theorem (which is famous too but not so deep as CRT): if $gcd(u, v) = 1$, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $au+bv=1$. Since $u|y$ and $v|y$, there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $y=mu$ and $y=nv$. Therefore, 
$$y=y*1=y(au+bv)=auv+bvy=au(nv)+bv(mu) = uv(an+bm),$$
which implies $uv|y$.

Comment: It is similar to my comment below my post and I think that this method is the most elementary !

Comment: Yes. Sorry I did not see your comments earlier.